# What is the meaning of std::function<void(Ref*)> in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, cocos2d-x

I got into trouble of this function, and I don't know what is the meaning of that:

```
menuItem1->setCallback([&](cocos2d::Ref *sender)
```

Enter the function, the param is ccMenuCallback&:

```
    /** set the callback to the menu item
    * @code
    * In js,can contain two params,the second param is jsptr
    * @endcode
    * @lua NA
    */
    void setCallback(const ccMenuCallback& callback);
```

And

```
typedef std::function<void(Ref*)> ccMenuCallback;
```

Answer (score 6):

That's a C++11 [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Basically `setCallback` accepts as an argument a [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) that takes a `cocos2d::Ref*` and returns `void`. That's a type which is able to hold a callable function.

A lambda is an anonymous function which in that situation is stored inside a `std::function<void(cocos2d::Ref*)>` variable and passed to the function.

Indeed it's something like:

```
auto lambda = [&](cocos2d::Ref* sender) {
  /* implementation */
};
// ^ store the anonymous function in a variable

menuItem1->setCallBack(lambda);
```

Answer (score 3):

std::function can hold function pointer, method binding, lambda expression and any object with overloaded operator()

```
void someFunc(cocos2d::Ref *sender)
{
    //some code
}

std::function<void(Ref*)> f1 = someFunc;
std::function<void(Ref*)> f2 = [&](cocos2d::Ref *sender) {
    //some code
}
```

Probably void setCallback(const ccMenuCallback& callback); takes a callback which is called when a menu item is clicked or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

This expression is a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
[&](cocos2d::Ref *sender)
```